# Change size of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, layout, size, jbutton

I have a **very** big problem. I need to do vertical menu in the center of window. What could be easier? What I did:

1. I create `JFrame` and set `BorderLayout` to it:
   `JFrame jfr = new JFrame("Frame");`
2. Then I create 4 buttons:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("b2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("b3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("b4");
```

3. I created panel and add all buttons to panel:

```
JPanel jpan = new JPanel();
jpan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpan, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
jpan.add(b1);
jpan.add(b2);
jpan.add(b3);
jpan.add(b4);
```

4. Aligned all buttons

```
b1.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
b2.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
b3.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
b4.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

5. And add panel to `JFrame`

```
jfr.add(jpan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Please help me to understand this layouts!
 Only say like this: "You should use this, when you use this layout"
 And now main question: *How* can I change size of buttons?

Comment: Here is a useful tutorial: [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of easy ways to change the size of buttons:

1. Give the buttons an icon of a different size.
2. Make the font of the buttons a different size.
3. Set more / less space between the button contents (the icon and text) and the border of the button.
4. Give the buttons more / less text.

Given the last is quite arbitrary, here is a demonstration of the first 3 techniques:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is what I searched!